# cocos2d-iPhone button Tap & Hold

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I would like to know how can I make a Tap & Hold action in cocos2d-iPhone buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Sneaky Input for your joystick/button? their button class can be setup so that it functions as a toggle, or only active on press(ie tap and hold). its somewhere on git hub and may be worth a look.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I'm using a simple button, I have looked at the joystick git on github but I want to use a simple button with a tap & hold function